# Table with 1 column, select FROM (column) WHERE (condition) until NULL (Empty Row), MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

Working with a excel sheet that is exported into a document with 1 column. Trying to have Access go through the entire sheet, find a operator ID number and then select all records from there until "Null" and place into another table based on the operator ID.

Table name (ACH) - Column Name (Records) - Operator ID A001885 - New Table (John)

Syntax I am trying:

```
SELECT  
[ACH].Record INTO [John]  
FROM  
[ACH]  
WHERE  
([ACH].Record) = "ENTERED BY OPERATOR: A001885")  
Select  
MAX.Record    
From[ACH]  
Where check = 0  
Order by [ACH]
```

I found similar questions and feel like I am close here but seem to be missing a piece!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean when you state: *"select all records from there until null"*?

Comment: Basically find this operator Id and from there select all records into that new table [John] until a blank line. Not sure if that makes sense but I can clarify further!

Comment: Should also mention I start a data science certificate on  2/28 so I wont have to ask such stupid questions soon!

Comment: Note that you cannot rely on the order of records processed during the evaluation of a query unless an ordering is specified (using an `ORDER BY` clause); similarly, when importing data from an external file, the order of records in the resulting table will not necessarily match the order of items in the external file.

Comment: Gotcha so it’s the fact that there’s no order by clause in there? Like so above?

Comment: You cannot order by a table, but by the values held by a field or fields within such table. It would help if you could post some sample data and an example of the desired result for the given sample data.

Comment: So the data comes through as a CSV file with all information input in column A so the data appears as
1 date  
2 text  
3 text  
4 ENTERED BY OPERATOR: A001885   
5 10 digit number  
6  '      '  
7  '      '  
8  '      '  
Ect '    '  
15+ Null or blank.   
I would like the query to read for that entered by line, select all records after until it reaches a blank line, then return the selected records to another table, I will repeat that query for each operator id